# operation on variable with date generate error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

How I can minus 30 minutes from variable?

```
#!/bin/bash

date_30=$(date --date '-30 min')
date_60=$($date_30 --date '-30 min')
    
exit 0
```

but I get

```
./a.sh: 4: ./a.sh: Thu: not found
```

Comment: What's wrong with `date --date '-60 min'`?

Comment: @KamilCuk he possibly wants to have second date relative to first date. `date --date '-60 min'` will produce a date relative to current timestamp witch may step-up to the next second between the two assignments.

Answer (score 1):

> `date_30=$(date --date '-30 min')`

This is storing the output of `date --date '-30 min'` into the `date_30` variable, which is something like: `Thu Aug 13 13:09:04 CEST 2020`

> `date_60=$($date_30 --date '-30 min')`

Executes the content of the `$date_30` variable with word splitting on space (since it has no enclosing double quotes `"`), so it tries to execute `Thu` with the parameters `Aug`, `13`, `13:09:04`, `CEST`, `2020`, `--date` and `-30 min` and surely there is no command named `Aug` and this is surely not what you try to do.

To fix it:

```sh
date_60=$(date --date "$date_30 -30 min")
```

Or use Shell arithmetic with timestamp dates:

```sh
# Store date 30 as timestamp
date_30=$(date +%s)

# Bash arithmetically subtract 1800 seconds (30 min)
date_60=$((date_30-1800))

# Print first date from timestamp into human readable
date --date "@$date_30"

# Print second date from timestamp into human readable
date --date "@$date_60"
```

Comment: so how to fix it?

Comment: @user3345547 Added solutions